# Figuring out what makes apache workers busy

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8aMu.png]
[image: states]

Something is causing my apache webserver to run out of workers and then the site slows down/becomes unavailable. This is a drupal based site, on the access log I cannot see too much useful information.

After restarting apache it works for couple of hours then the same thing happens again. This issue only come up in the recent week and now I have to restart apache twice a day.

How to go on to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You want [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html)!

```
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status

  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from .example.com
</Location>
```

You can now access server statistics by using a Web browser to access the page `http://your.server.name/server-status`.